# 1st Angular app is not working. Also why is angular so hard to install?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm learning angular for the first time and I can't get my first program to work.  Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS Tutorial Series</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">Hi {{ name }}, welcome to Angular     JS Tutorial Series</div>

    <!-- JS Scripts -->
    <script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-js\bower_components/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-js\bower_components/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("HelloController", function($scope)) {
    $scope.name = {
        "Roderick"
        };
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Why is angular so difficult to install?  I had to install so many npm stuff.  I'm also not sure how or where to create the CSS and JS folders.  Is it like Flask where the location of the folders matter?  Please help

The problem is the name 'Roderick' is not placed into the variable name.  The browser just shows the actual {{ name }} tag.

One last question.  I'm very new to web dev and frameworks.  I managed to learn the basics of HTML/CSS/JS but I haven't studied JQUERY or AJAX or PHP yet.  I'm wondering if angular is a good place to start learning front end for freelancing or I should try a simpler framework.  I also worked in Python Flask/Django but want something that will make me some money soon.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

angular can be difficult to grasp if you're not used to. But once you get things done, it becomes easier to develop in this awesome framework.

So, First things first, you need to reorder your code and folders and learn it that way. So, If you are learning I would do something like this:

```
 TEST-PROJECT
  ...... app.js
  ...... index.html
```

This is just a basic layout of your app for testing and learning.

Then you need to change your app to the app.js file

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Roderick";
    });
```

lastly, your html would be like this, adding the new app.js file that have your app.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <html ng-app="MyApp">

    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Tutorial Series</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="HelloController">Hi {{name}}, welcome to Angular     JS Tutorial Series</div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

And that would be it, Test it out, and lastly don't give up if it seems hard.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-related:

You're using local files from disk:

```
<script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-js\bower_components/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="C:\xampp\htdocs\angular-js\bower_components/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Pro tip: don't use `file:` protocol, use `http://localhost/`. Many, many things, frameworks, new JS APIs **do not work well or at all** in modern browsers with `file` protocol (this is for security reasons, or sometimes just because things are not well supported; I didn't check for angular but it's best to always develop using `localhost` in general).

Use some http server (if you use npm, do `npm install -g http-server` and then do `http-server -p 8080` in the root of the app to create ad-hoc server on `http://localhost:8080`.

Start from this, it might solve many of your future problems.

Then, check dev tools console for errors.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response and help.  I decided to use the file path out of desperation.  It was set to something less precise before.  Anyways, I installed http-server with npm but I didn't understand the second part about doing http-server -  p 8080.  Is that in the HTML code itself?  How do I incorporate it into code.

Comment: You'd do `cd /c/myproject/` then `http-server -p 8080` in your command line to start the server. It's a development tool that can start server ad-hoc in any folder without prior need for configuration. But I see you already use xampp so in fact you can just use `http://localhost` I guess since xampp seves stuff on port 80 already if I am not mistaken